# MySQL query to extract records based on another table field

Tags: mysql

I used a little MySQL years ago; now I forgotten a lot and I am lost.
Info: MySQL version 5.7.44 - PHP version 8.1.25
What I want to achieve should be simple: I have a DB with 2 tables [Components and Types in my example); they share the IDtype. This is a simple example:

```
Tables: 
Components [Code, Qty, IDtype]:
Code10, 2, 1
Code20, 10, 2
Code30, 5, 1
Code40, 3, 2
Code50, 7, 1
---

Types [Type, IDtype]:
Standard, 1
Special, 2
---
```

I want to obtain this result::

```
[Standard, 3] Code10, Code30, Code50
[Special, 2] Code20, Code40
```

Which is: the Type name and the number of retrieved records, followed by the list of extracted records
I tried without success several queries, the last one is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Components
WHERE  Components.IDtype = ALL (SELECT Types.IDtype FROM Types)";
```

This does not return anything.

Even this one that I found in another post does not do the job:

```
SELECT `KEY`, GROUP_CONCAT(Val SEPARATOR ",") as vals
  from table group by `KEY`;
```

Moreover, admitted that my last query is correct how reported I do not understand how to get the name and record count from the Types table since I only select the IDtype, not the whole record.
Thanks

Comment: Of note, MySQL Workbench is very handy for designing statements due to its real time validation of the formatting, not to mention its free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL queries with a combination of joins and grouping to aggregate the data from the `Components` and `Types` tables based on the `IDtype` column.

```
SELECT t.Type, COUNT(c.Code) AS Total,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.Code ORDER BY c.Code SEPARATOR ', ') AS Component_Codes
FROM Components c
INNER JOIN Types t ON c.IDtype = t.IDtype
GROUP BY t.Type;
```

[See this **db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/C8zyPWG4).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amit, I tried your query but it gives me an error.
This is my query (translated in Italian using the real names) and the error I get:

```
SELECT Tipi.Tipo, COUNT(Componenti.Codice) AS Total, GROUP_CONCAT (Componenti.Codice ORDER BY Componenti.Codice SEPARATOR ', ') AS CompCodes FROM Componenti INNER JOIN Tipi ON Componenti.IDtipo = Tipi.IDtipo GROUP BY Tipi.IDtipo
You have an error in your SQL syntax..to use near 'ORDER BY Componenti.Codice SEPARATOR ', ') AS CompCodes FROM Componenti INNER ' at line 2
```

Your fiddle works nicely even if there are a couple of points that I do not understand:

> FROM Components **c** INNER JOIN Types **t**

You used **c** as an alias for Components and **t** for Types, right?
If so, I should write ?

> FROM Componenti Componenti INNER JOIN Tipi Tipi

Strange syntax and anyway this does not change anything.